# Transferring GridView is not smooth on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to move a GridView with the ManipulationDelta event, similar to dragging.

My ManipulationDelta event looks like this:

```
private void GridView_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tt = (TranslateTransform)(sender as GridView).RenderTransform;
    tt.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    UpdateLayout();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it's not smooth at all. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the update layout call.

Changing the render transform is fast since it applies purely on the render thread and doesn't have to synchronize with the code thread or do a layout pass. UpdateLayout force everything to re-layout which is slow and unnecessary.

Comment: After removing the UpdateLayout() it is still not smooth. The GridView has 42 elements, maybe its a performance issue?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Without the UpdateLayout your ManipulationDelta is about as minimal as it can be and the number of elements on the GridView shouldn't matter for a RenderTransform. There's nothing more that can go wrong in the code you've shown, but there could be a problem elsewhere causing perf issues.